# How can I download a binary file submitted to gitlab over a trigger?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, webhooks

I want to push a file to a Gitlab pipeline from an external process using `curl` or a similar tool.

Uploading the file can be accomplished with a [Gitlab Trigger API request](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers):

```
curl -X POST \
     -F "token=$(cat .gitlab-trigger)" \
     -F "ref=develop" \
     -F "variables[env]=qua" \
     -F "bundle=@bundle.zip" \
     https://gitlab.company.com/api/v4/projects/1234/trigger/pipeline
```

The pipeline job can then access a [TRIGGER_PAYLOAD](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/#using-webhook-payload-in-the-triggered-pipeline) file similar to:

```json
{
  "ref": "develop",
  "variables": {
    "env": "qua"
  },
  "bundle": {
    "filename": "bundle.zip",
    "type": "application/octet-stream",
    "name": "bundle",
    "tempfile": "#\u003cFile:0x00007fcc8b7581e0\u003e",
    "head": "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"bundle\"; filename=\"bundle.zip\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n"
  },
  "id": "1228"
}
```

Judging from the file content it would appear that the `bundle.zip` file is uploaded to the Gitlab server.

**How can I get hold of the `bundle.zip` file? Is it even possible?**

Please note that

- Neither the bundle nor the temp file is found in the current dir or in the temporary parent dir of the TRIGGER_PAYLOAD file.
- Specifying the payload file as a `variables[bundle]` form param makes Gitlab reject the request as only strings and map variables are supported.
- Submitting the `token` and `variables[env]` variables as query params and adding the ZIP file as the binary only payload (no form params) makes the upload fail.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that uploading a file over the trigger API is not possible. A [new feature request](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/337210) has been made to Gitlab.

Feel free to push it if you agree that this feature is needed!